# How to create custom site column with type File

Tags: column, file

Reading MSDN documentation I see that we can define a type File for custom columns. When I define the site column in Elements.xml using  element and type file, the column does not get rendered. THe feature installs and activates fine without any issues. The other column I put in (for testing) is of type text and it gets deployed fine. However, the file type does not.

Please tell me how to work with this? There is not much on google for this either.

Also, when we store a file in document library or via a document set, how does its entry in the database gets linked to the filename?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing this through the web interface or SharePoint Designer. Simply, create a new content type that inherits from the Document content type and then add it to a Document Library. You will inherit the file field and you will also be able to add other fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to know this for better learning and understanding of sharepoint.